# Can Datomic simplify querying data contained in dynamically accessed HTML documents?

Tags: clojure, screen-scraping, data-processing, datomic

I need to write an API which would provide access to data being served as HTML documents from a web server. I need for my users to be able to perform queries over the data.

Say on a web site there is a page which lists items and their owners. Then there is additional set of profile pages for owners which for each owner provide information about their reputation. An example query I may need to answer is "Give me ID's and owners of all items submitted in 2013 whose owners have reputation of at least 10".

Given a query to answer, I need to be able to screen scrape only the parts of the web site I need for answering the query at hand. And ideally cache the obtained information for future use with new queries.

I have no problem writing the screen scraping part, but I am struggling with designing the storage/query/cache part. Is there something about Clojure/Datomic that makes it an especially suitable technology choice for this kind of processing of data? I have been pointed in this direction before.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a nice challenge but not sure about a few things: a) would you like to expose to your users a Datalog query box and so make them learn datalog-like syntax? b) what exact kind of results do you wish to cache, raw DB responses, html fomatted text, json ?

Anyway I suggest you to install and play a little bit with the Datomic console to get a grasp if you didn't before as it seems to me the more close idea to what you want to achieve atm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyuBnl0XQ6s http://blog.datomic.com/2013/10/datomic-console.html

For the API I suggest you to use http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/ as it provides sane defaults to implement REST services and let you focus on your app behaviour